# Estilos de css checkbox no funciona en firefox

Tags: css, html5

**El css no me funciona para firefox si alguien me puede ayudar**
tengo este estilo credo pero para algunos navegadores no funciona:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .es_carpeta {
            color:#999;
            margin-top: 0.3em;
        }
        .en_carpeta {
            color:#E2001A;
            margin-top: 0.3em;
        }
        .check {
            position: relative;
            width: 40px;
            background:#E2001A;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top: 1px;
        }
        .check:before {
            content:'';
            position: absolute;
            width: 35px;
            height: 19px;
            background: #3d3d3d;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
       .check:after{
           content:'';
           position: absolute;
           width: 18px;
           height: 18px;
           background: #fff;
           transition: 0.25s;
           border: 2px solid #999;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           border-radius: 25px;
       }
       .check:checked:after{
           left: 18px;
           border:2px solid #E2001A;
       }

       .check:checked:before{
         background:  #E2001A;
       }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
      <h1>English</h1>
      <span class ="es">español</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
      <span class ="en">ingles</span>
</body>
</html>
```

He intentado buscar respuesta en internet. me estoy iniciando en el desarrollo web y me gustaría aprender mucho mas de css y js. aquí  les dejo el código para que me puedan ayudar, y resolver el problema sea mas fácil.  me gustaría que funcionara en todos los navegadores con el mismo código pero al parecer Firefox recose estos estilos de css, espero este entendible el código

Busqué otros estilos y tampoco me funcionaron pero como este es el mas fácil  que hice y esta totalmente sencillo por eso les muestro este, ante mano Muchas gracias. Y disculpen las molestias caudadas.

Espero me puedan ayudar en esta oportunidad, nuevamente muchas gracias

Comment: Ya determinaste cuales estilos en especifico son los que dan problemas? Hay algunos que necesitan ciertos parámetros para un determinado navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tal vez usar la propiedad `appearance: none;`, `-moz-appearance: none;` en la clase `.check` del css, sin embargo tiene una advertencia de la que tendrías que estar consiente y te la dejo a continuación.

[Aquí la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/appearance), dejo también un poco de lo que dice en la página:

> No estándar: Esta característica no es parte de los estándares. No la uses en sitios Web en producción: no funcionará para todos los usuarios. Podrían haber también incompatibilidades considerables entre distintas implementaciones y el comportamiento podría cambiar en el futuro.
>
> **La propiedad CSS -moz-appearance se utiliza en Gecko (Firefox) para visualizar un elemento utilizando una plataforma nativa basada en el estilo del tema del sistema operativo.**

```css
.es_carpeta {
    color:#999;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.en_carpeta {
    color:#E2001A;
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.check {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    background:#E2001A;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;

    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.check:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 35px;
    height: 19px;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

 .check:after{
     content:'';
     position: absolute;
     width: 18px;
     height: 18px;
     background: #fff;
     transition: 0.25s;
     border: 2px solid #999;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 25px;

 }
 .check:checked:after{
     left: 18px;
     border:2px solid #E2001A;

 }

 .check:checked:before{
   background:  #E2001A;

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>English</h1>
    <span class ="es">español</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
    <span class ="en">ingles</span>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Resultado sin usar appearance:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Utilizando appearance:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar CSS puro compatible con todo, incluyendo FireFox.

Te dejo un ejemplo que funciona muy bien y lo puedes acoplar a tu gusto, aunque ya te hayan dado una respuesta antes.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
body .wrap {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 125px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
}
body .wrap:first-of-type {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
body .wrap:first-of-type .inner {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
body .wrap:first-of-type .outer {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
body .wrap:first-of-type .outer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #03001e, #7303c0, #ec38bc);
}
body .wrap:first-of-type input:checked ~ .outer {
  -webkit-animation: shift 0.8s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
          animation: shift 0.8s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
body .wrap:first-of-type input:checked ~ .outer:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #03001e, #7303c0, #ec38bc);
}
@-webkit-keyframes shift {
  0% {
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(150px) rotate(180deg);
            transform: translateX(150px) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes shift {
  0% {
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(150px) rotate(180deg);
            transform: translateX(150px) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
body .wrap:first-of-type input:checked ~ .outer ~ .inner {
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(150px);
          transform: translateX(150px);
  box-shadow: inset 5px -10px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
body .wrap:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
body .wrap:nth-of-type(2) input:checked {
  z-index: 7;
}
body .wrap:nth-of-type(2) input:checked ~ .outer {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 150px;
}
body .wrap:nth-of-type(2) input:checked ~ .inner {
  margin-left: 150px;
  box-shadow: inset 5px -10px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
body .outer, body input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  border-radius: 80px;
  opacity: 0;
}
body .outer:nth-of-type(2), body input:nth-of-type(2) {
  z-index: 8;
}
body .outer {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #03001e, #7303c0, #ec38bc);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50px 50px;
          transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, margin 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, margin 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
body .inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset -5px -10px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-position: -35px -30px;
  background-size: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 115px);
  top: calc(50% - 40px);
  border-radius: 500%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="outer">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <div class="outer">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo probé en Firefox y no tuvo problemas, tu lo puedes adecuar como quieras.

[Te dejo más ejemplos](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/css-checkbox-styles/)